# How to share common code across different ECR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

Is there a way for **common code to be shared across different ECR repositories**, and can different ECR repositories fetch a common piece of code such that if changes are pushed to the common code, they are reflected in all ECR repositories without pushing new ECR image versions?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: okay will do that if I feel so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way for common code to be shared across different ECR repositories?

I assume you are asking whether you can share code across different *images*. Yes, you could leverage [multi-stage](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/#use-an-external-image-as-a-stage) builds for this.

For instance, Docker image A could build a certain binary then Docker image B could pull it in.

> such that if changes are pushed to the common code, they are reflected in all ECR repositories without pushing new ECR image versions?

There's nothing out of the box for this, but this shouldn't be hard to implement. Assuming that the code lives on a git repository, you could use whatever CI/CD system is available to trigger a re-build of all the images.